# Is 80k btus enough for this 1850 square foot house?

Tags: heat

I live on boarder of 5 and 6 heat zone and when temp gets around 0-10 degrees furnace has a hard time to reach 66 degrees, it will only get to 60. House is 1850 square feet plus a basement that has a vent going to it. Furnace is a year 2013 heil putting out 80k btus at 96% so 78k. House is from 1960s half the house is a addition from the 90s, house is insulated but probably r13 in walls some blown in insulation in older half ceiling but vaulted ceilings in new with r13. Old owner had the new furnace replace a 2 furnace setup probably older units. My question: is new furnace big enough? If not do I have to get a bigger unit installed or can l add  a 40k unit for additional capacity when to cold out.

Comment: Would you like an inexpensive auxiliary furnace *that doesn't require electricity to run*?   We use a 50,000 BTU Williams Monterey wall furnace that sits in an interior wall and heats both sides. They're only 70-80% efficient (because they're using convection to vent exhaust and to distribute heat) but they ignore power outages.  You could use one as second-tier (emergency) heat to supplement your heat on cold days, and keep the house from freezing on power-out.  https://www.homedepot.com/p/Williams-Monterey-Top-Vent-Wall-Heater-50-000-BTUH-70-AFUE-Natural-Gas-5009622A/311801074

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica minor problem, it needs gas

Comment: @Ruskes yes, it works when the power is out so it needs fuel.  It also needs an exhaust vent, but OP probably has a spare.

Comment: Get a thermal image analysis done to see where the heat losses are. May be cheaper to fix them than pay for boiler and running costs.

Comment: @Ruskes  Propane versions are available also, if OP does not have gas service.  Tank rental might suck.

Comment: @crip659 and you are recommending having a propane tank in the living room

Comment: @Ruskes  Tank sits outside and propane is piped in, usually a 1000 pounder, but can use 100 pound tanks if just for the odd time.

Comment: Without doing a heat load calculation, it's impossible to say whether your furnace is undersized for the space, though that certainly seems to be the likely situation based on what you're saying.  It matters immensely on what type (and number) of windows you have, wall and ceiling insulation, and other factors that determine the needed furnace size.  I'd suggest having an efficiency analysis done by your local energy supplier to see where your heat losses are, and then remediate those first and see what they'd recommend.